# missing operand; found END

Tags: javascript

I don't know why I'm getting this error.

```
missing operand; found END
```

Whenever I make a new line, it appears at the bottom, so right now it's saying there's a problem with the last line.

Here is my code:

```
alert("Hello, and welcome to [title undecided] by ARADPLAUG!");
alert("If there's a yes or no question, just say yes or no, no nah's or sure's or yup's or anything like that.");
alert("You have four stat points to begin with. If you enter something wrong, you get -1 stat point.");
var choice1 = prompt("Choose one perk: STRENGTH, INTELLIGENCE, ENDURANCE, ALERTNESS or SPEED.").toLowerCase();
var choice2 = prompt("Choose one perk: STRENGTH, INTELLIGENCE, ENDURANCE, ALERTNESS or SPEED.").toLowerCase();
var choice3 = prompt("Choose one perk: STRENGTH, INTELLIGENCE, ENDURANCE, ALERTNESS or SPEED.").toLowerCase();
var beginning = prompt("You're running from a fire when you suddenly see a lake. Do you JUMP in it, keep RUNning, or FILL a bucket with it?").toLowerCase();
switch (beginning) {
    case 'run':
        alert("You run away from the scary water, into the safety of the fire. -YOU HAVE DIED-");
        break;
    case 'fill':
        var bucket = prompt("You have two buckets. Do you want to fill ONE or BOTH of them with water?").toLowerCase();
        break;
    case 'jump':
        if (choice1 === "alertness" || choice2 === "alertness" || choice3 === "alertness") {
            var branch = prompt("You jump into the water just in time. A branch above you looks like it's about to fall off. Do you want to SHAKE it off now and be alert or WAIT and hope it won't fall off?").toLowerCase();
        } else if (choice1 || choice2 || choice3 === "speed") {
            var cave = prompt("You jump out of the way just before a branch crushes you. It uncovers a hole leading to a cave. Do you enter it?");
        } else {
            alert("You look up, and see the branch fall just before it crushes your neck, killing you instantly. -YOU HAVE DIED- ");
        }
        break;
    default:
        alert("Sorry, that wasn't one of the options. The fire consumes you. -YOU HAVE DIED-");
        switch (branch) {
            case 'wait':
                if (choice1 === "speed" || choice2 === "speed" || choice3 === "speed") {
                    prompt("You jump out of the way just before the branch crushes you. It uncovers a hole leading to a cave. Do you enter it?");
                } else {
                    alert("You look up, and see the branch fall just before it crushes your neck, killing you instantly. -YOU HAVE DIED- ");
                }
                break;
            case 'shake':
                var cave2 = prompt("You shake the branch, causing it to fall. It uncovers a hole. Do you enter it?");
                break;
            default:
                alert("That wasn't one of the options. The branch falls and crushes you.  -YOU HAVE DIED-");
```

Comment: You're missing a `}`.

Comment: Just add `}}` on the end.

Comment: In addition to the answer. One of the great tools to debug things like that is [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net). You can copy your code into the script section then click the `JSHint` button you can see the message `Missing '}'` and the line in question has a red dot to the left of it. It's a great tool and helped me a lot, specially it's auto-formatting feature `TidyUp` is great for finding missing braces and the likes.

Comment: Tools like http://www.jshint.com/ or a GOOD IDE should pick up on the error.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `}` to close your `switch{...}` blocks. "Unexpected `$end`" usually means you have levels of brackets/parentheses/braces that are not closed properly.

Comment: +1. I think the outer switch is also missing one. Might need add a second `}`. I could be wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a javascript guy, but your switch is opening a `{` and you are not having a matching closing  `}`